# I'm not able to globally load the color tokens using vue3 + vite

Tags: javascript, vue.js, sass, vuejs3, vite

[image]

my vite config file looks like this.
but it wont load the color tokens and throws error in application run time
[image]

i'm using node latest version 18.13.0 and vue 3 with vite 3.2.4 and sass 1.56.1

I want to load color token globally in my application

Comment: Is the `$i....` sass variable defined?

Comment: yes it is defined in token.scss file which I have imported as shown in first image